# Python Sublime and XDebug

Tags: python

I have installed XDebug as well as Python Debugger.
I have written a simple program: `print("OK")`. 
I was also able to do `Ctrl + B` and `build`.
However, all I get in the console is: `[Finished in 0.1s]` while I would like to see the output as well:`"OK"`. 
`Tools > XDebug` has no Run command, nor has it Step In command nor any other command that would help me run my program. 
How do I recover from this situation, please?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your whole code?

If you, for example, wrote -

```
def do_stuff():
     print("doin' stuff")
```

and then just compiled that it would build but not output anything since no function call was made.

Answer (score 0):

def do_stuff():
    print("doin' stuff")

Hit Ctrl+B

Output:

[Finished in 0.1s]